# Changing User Agent in OSMDroid

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

Is it possible to change `User Agent` I send with every tile request in OSMDroid?

I'm currently getting `403 Forbidden` error whenever I try to download a tile ([as described in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191767/osmdroid-and-mapnik-tile-provider-no-longer-working)), probably because OSMDroid itself has been banned.

Comment: osmdroid hasn't been banned, just the (wrong) user-agent it supplies by default. Setting a *valid* user-agent is required by the [tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only way to specify the User Agent is to modify OSMDroid's `MapTileDownloader.loadTile()` method in the following way:

```
final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpUriRequest head = new HttpGet(tileURLString);
head.setHeader("User-Agent", "OSMDroid"); // Add this line
final HttpResponse response = client.execute(head);
```

It solves the `403 Forbidden` tile download problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow [Issue 515](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=515) to track this issue. We have implemented a fix and we will release a proper update soon. We will be providing a factory interface for customizing the user-agent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just downloaded the following jar file

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/osmdroid/osmdroid-android/4.1/osmdroid-android-4.1.jar

It's the `osmdroid-android-4.1.jar` , put it in your `/Libs` project folder.