# Openstreetmap HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

i have created an app with the openstreetmap api and i'm using the OsmBonusPack library when i tried to get location with getFromLocationName() fontion i get a forbiden error

```
BONUSPACK: Invalid response from server: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exact URL does this response come from?

Comment: This URL : http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&accept-language=en&addressdetails=1&limit=1&q=brazil

Comment: Works without problems here. Maybe you have been blocked. Did you respect [Nominatim's usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Usage_Policy)?

Comment: How can i identify my app ?

Comment: You mean setting a valid user agent? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217781/changing-user-agent-in-osmdroid

Comment: Ok if i understood i need to add this line : head.setHeader("User-Agent", "OSMDroid"); But where exactly

Comment: According to the link I mentioned you have to modify `MapTileDownloader.loadTile()`.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue. Inconsiderate users of osmdroid have failed to set the user agent correctly and as such, have gotten everyone banned from osm's tile servers.

Documented here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/366

Put this in your activity before loading the map.

`OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);`