# Android MapView Tiles Empty

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to display a map of a city based on the user's location that can be used both online and offline (in case signal is poor). For some reason, I can display the mapview but I just get an empty screen of blank tiles.

Any thoughts why this is happening?

**What's Hot Fragment**

```
MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;
    MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = null;
    MapController myMapController = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);

        final MapView mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
        int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
        marker.setBounds(0, markerHeight, markerWidth, 0);

        // save zip to sd
        AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
        InputStream is;
        String fileName = "map_new_haven.zip";    // the zip file lies in assets root
        String path = this.getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + fileName; // the path I save SD to

        File tileFile = new File(path);
        if(!tileFile.exists()) {
            try {
                is = assetManager.open(fileName);

                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(path);

                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                    fo.write(b, 0, length);
                }

                fo.flush();
                fo.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        IArchiveFile[] archives = new IArchiveFile[1];
        archives[0] = ArchiveFileFactory.getArchiveFile(tileFile);

        // Simple implementation that extends BitmapTileSourceBase and nothing else
        ITileSource customTiles = new XYTileSource("MapQuest", null, 10, 14, 256, ".jpg");  // MapQuest is the name of the folder inside the zip (so zip is map.zip and inside it is a folder called MapQuest)

        MapTileModuleProviderBase[] providers = new MapTileModuleProviderBase[2];
        providers[0] = new MapTileFileArchiveProvider(new SimpleRegisterReceiver(getActivity().getApplicationContext()), customTiles, archives);    // this one is for local tiles (zip etc.)
        providers[1] =  new MapTileDownloader(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);    // MAPNIK web tile source

        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);

        MapTileProviderArray tileProvider = new MapTileProviderArray(customTiles, 
                new SimpleRegisterReceiver(getActivity().getApplicationContext()), providers);
        TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);  // this makes sure that the invisble tiles of local tiles are transparent so we can see tiles from web, transparent have a minor performance decline.

        mapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);

        mapView.invalidate();

        myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(getActivity(), mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

        myMapController = mapView.getController();
        myMapController.setZoom(3);

        ScaleBarOverlay myScaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(getActivity());
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myScaleBarOverlay);

        myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
               } 
           });

        return rootView;
    }
```

**MyItemizedOverlay**

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

 private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

 public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable pDefaultMarker,
   ResourceProxy pResourceProxy) {
  super(pDefaultMarker, pResourceProxy);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 public void addItem(GeoPoint p, String title, String snippet){
  OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem(title, snippet, p);
  overlayItemList.add(newItem);
  populate(); 
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSnapToItem(int arg0, int arg1, Point arg2, IMapView arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return overlayItemList.get(arg0);
 }

 @Override
 public int size() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return overlayItemList.size();
 }

}
```

I'm fairly certain that the file is in the folder that I specified and I tried running this on both an internet connected mode and on airplane mode(offline). Both show the mapview but just blank white tiles.

[image: Blank Tiles]

**LogCat**

```
02-11 13:41:23.343: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 14(0x3139322e313633),sn(),family 0,flags 4
02-11 13:41:23.343: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo-, SUCCESS
02-11 13:41:23.343: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 22(0x74696c652e6f70),sn(),family 0,flags 4
02-11 13:41:23.343: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
02-11 13:41:23.343: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 22(0x74696c652e6f70),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
02-11 13:41:23.343: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1
02-11 13:41:23.343: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+
02-11 13:41:23.353: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
02-11 13:41:23.353: I/global(26293): call createSocket() return a new socket.
02-11 13:41:23.353: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 14(0x3139322e313633),sn(),family 0,flags 4
02-11 13:41:23.353: D/libc(26293): [NET] getaddrinfo-, SUCCESS
02-11 13:41:23.453: W/org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileDownloader(26293): Problem downloading MapTile: /3/3/3 HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: What your logcat says? post the logcat

Comment: Your title is quite ambiguous. Maybe "Google Maps not rendering" or something like that. I thought you were talking about the data structure.

Comment: `/3/3/3 HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`

Comment: Just follow this [link](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=515) for your issue.

Comment: I'm still a little confused? Where do I put that patch and how do I use it?

Comment: Read carefully they have told what to do with that.

Comment: Don't bother with the patch for the osmdroid jar. Download version 4.1 instead. This has the user-agent correction built in.

Comment: Sure you have your API Key set up properly?

Comment: @android_guy is right. I found related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191767/osmdroid-and-mapnik-tile-provider-no-longer-working, probably this one should be tagged as a duplicate